# php not work on hebrew folder

Tags: php, xampp, hebrew

I have a php file php in a Hebrew folder
But the file does not work I get the following message

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/demo/צור-קשר/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

How can I make the php work with a Hebrew folder?

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: Look at this question it may be relevant to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703711/php-mkdir-in-hebrew-creates-gibrish-folder

Comment: i am using  Version 5.5.15

Comment: What's the structure/hierarchy of your files? And I don't think if using UTF-8 (such as hebrew) characters as file-naming is a good practice.

Comment: That's because different functions use different character encodings (I don't know who had this brilliant idea!) You have to try `utf8_encode()` or `utf8_decode()` until it works.

Comment: Better yet, @Aloso, fix the root issue if it's a charset issue ;-)

Comment: @Qirel So, what's the root issue? I'd say the root issue is that PHP doesn't use utf-8 by default, like any other modern programming language.

Comment: Better set headers, configs and whatever else to utf8, that way everything is, and you don't have to worry about it, and don't have to use `utf8_**code()` functions @Aloso - and using those functions require you to know what the current encoding is too. Although I really agree, it should be utf8 by default

Comment: Header, config, file encoding, etc. doesn't influence the way these built-in functions work. I ran into this problem a while ago, and I've heard from others who couldn't solve it either, except by explicitly converting strings with these ugly `utf8_**code()` functions.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you change the folder name from the Hebrew `צור-קשר` to an English equivalent name. Whatever solves your current problem would still leave more potential problems ahead. Avoid them all by using the basic English characters for paths and filenames.

Comment: @Aloso Most functions that "cannot" work with UTF-8 characters have a `mb_**()` function, like tieres `mb_strtolower()` for multibyte characters. https://3v4l.org/16R71